# jQuery and CSS click on two elements at once

Tags: jquery, css

This might be impossible but I'm gonna ask anyway:

I got the image slider plugin from http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php
But I want the prev and next buttons to be invisible and underlayed under the first and third image. While clicking on the image to enlarge it in another div I want the button behind the image to be also clicked. The code:

```
<div style="width: 300px; position: relative;">
    <button class="prev" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute; left: 0;"></button>
    <button class="next" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute; right: 0;"></button>
    <div class="slide">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://mario.nintendo.com/img/mario_logo.png" class="thumbprofilpic" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" onclick="picid(this)"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://mario.nintendo.com/img/mario_logo.png" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" onclick="picid(this)"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://mario.nintendo.com/img/mario_logo.png" class="thumbprofilpic" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" onclick="picid(this)"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://mario.nintendo.com/img/mario_logo.png" class="thumbprofilpic" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" onclick="picid(this)"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://mario.nintendo.com/img/mario_logo.png" class="thumbprofilpic" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" onclick="picid(this)"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousellite.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".slide").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".next",
    btnPrev: ".prev",
    circular: false
    });
});

function picid(z){
    var selected = '<img src="' + $(z).attr('src') + '" style="width: 300px">';
    $("#showfullsize").html(selected);
}
</script>

<div id="showfullsize"></div>
```

Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: So you want to both open the image and go to the next/previous image?

Comment: `buttons behind the image to be also clicked` Both at same time? What behaviour are you expecting of clicking on next/prev buttons both at once???

Comment: Sry I mean just the one button behind the image

Comment: Either you downvoters check the code AND THE PLUGIN exactly or you just GTFO please. Sick of it

Answer (score 2):

In a quick-reply method -- you can trigger any click from within a click for example:

```
$('#element1').on('click',function(e) {
    $('#element2').trigger('click'); 
});

$('#element2').click(function(e) {
    alert('i was triggered'); 
});
```

Comment: To clarify, would the code for both go where `alert('i was triggered');` is?

Comment: This will not work, please try the same plugin to understand it better

Comment: this should definitely work. may be easier written as: $('#element1').on('click',function(e) {
    $('#element2').click(); 
});

Comment: This basic stuff will NOT work. As I sayd check also the plugin, just download it from where I mentioned and just copy the code and you will see why

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can fire a click event on the fly

```
function picid(z) {
    var selected = '<img src="' + $(z).attr('src') + '" style="width: 300px">';
    $("#showfullsize").html(selected);

    // whatever the selectors are for your prev/next buttons
    $('.prev, .next', '#plugin-container').click();
}
```

Although I'm very curious as to what the use-case for this looks like...

Comment: The selectors for the next/prev buttons are in the plugin class which I mentioned but it's very complicated to edit because I'm new in jQuery